# Not able to install google-chrome in Fedora21

Tags: google-chrome, fedora-21

## I am trying to install google-chrome in fedora21

Things i did:

> $ sudo yum update
>
> $ cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
>
> ---

```
      [google-chrome]

      name=google-chrome - \$basearch

      baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/\$basearch

      enabled=1

      gpgcheck=1

      EOF
```

---

> $ yum install google-chrome-stable

## But getting this error:

> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-61.0.3163.79-1.x86_64
>   (google-chrome)
>              Requires: libssl3.so(NSS_3.28)(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-61.0.3163.79-1.x86_64
>   (google-chrome)
>              Requires: libnss3.so(NSS_3.22)(64bit)

How can i solve this problem??? please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that Fedora 21 does not have libraries new enough to support the recent build of Chrome you've downloaded. Fedora 21 on December 1st, 2015 — almost two years ago — and has not been receiving security updates or fixes since then. Please update to the current release (right now, Fedora 26).

I can verify for sure that `nss` in Fedora 26 *does* provide the required versions for libnss, so that will solve this problem.